# How to refer object inside nested method

Tags: javascript

Have following code.

```
object.waypoint=function () {
    this.uw=setInterval( function() {
       console.log(this);
    }, 200);
}
```

How do I refer to "object" inside function on line three, I tried it with "this" keyword but it doesn't seem to refer the object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside setInterval `this` refers to window. You'll need to make a variable that references to `this`.

```
object.waypoint=function () {
    var me = this;

    this.uw=setInterval( function() {
       console.log(me);
    }, 200);
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I tried that already but didn't insert "var" keyword, this one works. :)

Comment: @Otto-VilleLamminpää Please accept an answer if you found the solution to your question.

Answer (score 1):

A common way is to store a reference to `this` in a variable, that you then can use to get access to the proper `this`:

```
object.waypoint=function () {
    // Keep a reference to this in a variable
    var that = this;
    that.uw=setInterval( function() {
       // Now you can get access to this in here as well through the variable
       console.log(that);
    }, 200);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think `bind` is a neat solution - It isn't implemented in all browsers but there are [workarounds](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind#Compatibility).

```
object.waypoint = function(){
    this.uw = setInterval(function(){
        console.log(this);
    }.bind(this), 200);
}
```

See the [MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) for proper documentation